# Mysqldump Error: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Tags: mysql

I use mysqldump and get error.
In my config files writed property for sql_mode and in mysql console global and session property similary.

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Error:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p  --compatible=ansi --skip-extended-insert --compact Terminal > dump.sql

mysqldump: Error: 'Expression #6 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY 
clause and contains nonaggregated column 'information_schema.FILES.EXTRA' 
which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by' when trying to dump tablespaces
```

if i use this property in my.cnf for [mysqldump] i get error...

```
mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'sql_mode=IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

How do i fix that?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have this error in mysqldump with the parameter *mysqldump --compatible=ansi ...*

It works without this parameter.